# MySQL Where IN, limit output

Tags: mysql, limit, where-in

So I have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,2,3) LIMIT 10
```

Is it possible to limit the number of output for each of element in array like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id 1 LIMIT 10
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id 2 LIMIT 10
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id 3 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using variables:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         @seq := IF(id = @id, @seq + 1,
                    IF(@id := id, 1, 1)) AS seq 
  FROM table 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @id := 0) AS vars
  WHERE id IN (1,2,3) 
  ORDER BY id) AS t
WHERE t.seq <= 10
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're scared of MySQL variables (I am), you could also use a `UNION` query:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2 LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 3 LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: the IN array is dynamically generated and working with very large datasets.  This query would have performance bottleneck?

Comment: Then the @Giorgos answer might be what you are looking for.